# JSON data comparison in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am doing a college project. In category page there will be product categories coming from json-

```
[{
        "code": "mc",
        "name": "Mobile",
        "desc": "We provide range of latest mobile phones with best price in the market",
        "imageUrl": "images/mobile.jpg"

    },
    {
        "code": "lc",
        "name": "Laptops",
        "desc": "Huge sale is going on Lenova,HP and Apple's laptop",
        "imageUrl": "images/lappy.jpg"

    },
    {
        "code": "ic",
        "name": "ipads",
        "desc": "ipad mini is available with the cheapest price.Go grab the offer",
        "imageUrl": "images/ipad.jpg"

    },
    {
        "code": "sc",
        "name": "Storage Devices",
        "desc": "All kind of storage devices are available here",
        "imageUrl": "images/storage.jpg"

    }
]
```

As the category list is dynamic for eg 4, trying to build up link to list page depends on the category based on code data in JSON. For example if click on mobile in category.html, result.html will be mobile list, if iPad then iPad list. Right now category page done and trying to pass and receive code in JSON to compare in condition to display concerned data like laptop or desktop.

Present js is:

```
      var catApp = angular.module("catApp", ["ngStorage"]);
      catApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $localStorage){
        $http.get('categories.json').success(function(data) {
          $scope.categories = data;
        });
 $scope.save = function() {
      window.location.replace('result.html');
      $scope.type=categories;
               if(type.code=='mc'){
                    localStorage.setItem('msg1', 'Mobiles');
                }
                $scope.data1 = localStorage.getItem('msg1');
      });
```

to display it on result.html-

```
<body ng-app="catApp">
<div ng-controller="CountryCtrl">
 {{data1}}
</div>
</body>
```

---

Please help me to display product name in result.html comparing the 'code' from the json.
In short want to display category name in result.html depends on which category user click where category also dynamic coming from json with a fag value code to make it work like-

freshtechsample.tk/pal/test.html

Only difference is in above html links are static, in required page links are dynamic.

Present output:http://freshtechsample.tk/pal/category.html

Comment: you generally use angular for a single page application and should look into using an angular router rather than loading a whole new page. When you load a whole new page all the script on current page is gone so it does no good setting the response data to `$scope` ... especially since `window.replace` will block anything after it

Comment: suggest you go through some tutorials

Comment: No idea why you are using `location.replace` and multiple html pages. This is not how to create an angular app. Go through tutorial on docs site to see how single page app should be constructed https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial